# How to have fragment-replace and additional UI change happen together?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My MainActivity has a TabLayout that I'm showing(View.VISIBILE) when certain fragments(say type A) are loaded and hiding(View.GONE) when other fragments(say type B) are loaded.

Now while transitioning between type A and type B fragments - the TabLayout and the fragment don't load together. First the TabLayout becomes visible and the previous fragment shifts down, then the new fragment replaces the old fragment. Of course this happens in milliseconds but some visible effect is there on looking carefully.

How can I make sure both TabLayout visibility change and fragment replace happen together?

Here is the code to load fragments in MainActivity.java:

```
    ...
    private View mTitleWithTabs = findViewById(R.id.title_and_hometabs);
    ...

    @UiThread
    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction
                .add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        if (/* type A fragment */) {
            setTabsHomeButtonSelected(true);  // setting an ImageView as selected or not
            scrollAndSelectTabAtPositionOnlyUI(0);
            mTitleWithTabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            setTabsHomeButtonSelected(false);
            mTitleWithTabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Here is the relevant code from activity_main.xml

```
    ...
    <include
        android:id="@+id/title_and_hometabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/title_with_hometabs"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/exo_mini"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_and_hometabs"/>
   ...
```

Here is title_with_hometabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/title_with_hometabs"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:paddingStart="35dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".90"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorViewAll"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_22" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_browser"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorDivider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home_button_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/home" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorDivider" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_list"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabRippleColor="@null"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabLanguages"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDivider" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was to use getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions() after calling commit() inside the loadFragment() method in MainActivity.java.

This is because the delay between additional UI element in MainActivity and fragment-load was coming because of FragmentManager.commit() being asynchronous.

Other ways that I explored and didn't work:

- Using FragmentManager.commitNow() doesn't work because I need the backstack.
- Using FragmentManager.runOnCommit(additionUIElementChangeRunnable) doesn't also allow the fragment transaction to be added the backstack.

Note: FragmentManager.commitNow() doesn't allow using backstack because ordering guarantee in backstack can't be provided when commitNow is used with commit.